# Range Conditional validation in ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have two fields "Price From" and "Price To" + "Currency Unit'.

I want to make sure that:
- if "From" and "To" both have values, then "Price To" should be ">" "Price From".
- if "any" of "Price To" or "Price From" has a value, to make "Currency Unit" required.

Can this be achieved in a custom validator? If yes, where do I place it, on which field? Or could it be possible I create a model-level validator to run on client and server sides?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle the validation in the model as model-level validation by specifying the  `IValidatableObject` interface, and defining the required `Validate()` method, like this:

```
public class Address : IValidatableObject
{

    public int PriceTo { get; set; }
    public int PriceFrom { get; set; }
    public int CurrencyUnit { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {

        var results = new List<ValidationResult>();

        if(PriceFrom != null && PriceTo != null)
        {
            if( ! PriceTo > PriceFrom )
            {
                results.Add (new ValidationResult("\"Price To\" must be greater than \"Price From\"", new List<string> { "PriceTo", "PriceFrom" }));
            }

        }

        if(PriceFrom != null || PriceTo != null)
        {
            if(CurrencyUnit == null)
            {
                results.Add (new ValidationResult("If you indicate any prices, you must specify a currency unit"", new List<string> { "CurrencyUnit" }))
            }
        }
        return results;
    }
}
```

**NOTE, however**: I don't think your MVC client-side validation picks up this rule, so it will only apply server-side.

Comment: Hello Faust, thanks for this, I still need to try it. I always thought I can only validate properties and not whole model. Is there a way to add client side validation?

Answer (score 1):

There's a nice example [**here**](http://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/the-complete-guide-to-validation-in-asp.net-mvc-3-part-2) which you'll have to slightly adapt, but essentialy I think this is the technique you are looking for, which is both **client** and server validation.